How do I delete rows that doesn't contain a string in Pandas?
Say I have the following dataset:
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> data = {'index': [0, 1, 2], 'value': ['zero', 1, 'two']}
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
   index value
0      0  zero
1      1     1
2      2   two

I want to remove all the rows which in the column 'value' does not contain a string, so in this example, I want to remove the second row (or the row with index 1).
Rather naively I've tried to run:
df[isinstance(df['value'], str)]

However, this results in a error. For context, the actual dataset I'm working on has thousands of rows.

isinstance can check only single element but df has many elements. It may needs to use for-loop or .apply() to run isinstance on every element separatelly

isinstance can check only single element but df has many elements. It may needs to use for-loop or .apply() to run isinstance on every element separatelly
df[ df['value'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)) ]


You can do this by 'apply' function. Try this:
# Remove rows where 'value' column is not a string
df = df[df['value'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]

print(df)

